What are the boundary conditions on the Green's function?
Let a linear ordinary differential equation of the form $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) = g(x)\tag{1}$$ be given to us subject to the boundary conditions on $f(x)$ and/or $f^\prime(x)$. The most general solution to this equation is
$$
f(x) = f_0(x) + \int G(x, x') g(x') dx'
$$
where $f_0(x)$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) =0\tag{2}$$ and $G(x,x')$ is obtained by solving $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}G(x,x') = \delta(x-x').\tag{3}$$
My question is, what boundary conditions should be used on the Green function $G(x,x')$ (and/or on its derivative) to solve equation (3)? Same as those provided for $f(x)$ and $f^\prime(x)$? If so, why?
